# integrate vue-i18n in vue-beautiful-chat

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I try to integrate (vue-i18n) at this library (https://github.com/mattmezza/vue-beautiful-chat) in src folder but I have some integration problems
so,
in this file ./i18n/translations.js => we have the translations
in src/index.js

```
import Launcher from './Launcher.vue'
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from './i18n/translations.js'

const defaultComponentName = 'beautiful-chat'

const Plugin = {
  install (Vue, options = {}) {
    /**
     * Makes sure that plugin can be installed only once
     */
    if (this.installed) {
      return
    }

    Vue.use(VueI18n)
    const locale = navigator.language
    const i18n = new VueI18n({
      fallbackLocale: 'fr',
      locale: locale,
      messages
    })

    this.installed = true
    this.event = new Vue({i18n})
    this.dynamicContainer = null
    this.componentName = options.componentName || defaultComponentName
    /**
     * Plugin API
     */
    Vue.prototype.$chat = {
      _setDynamicContainer (dynamicContainer) {
        Plugin.dynamicContainer = dynamicContainer
      }
    }
    /**
     * Sets custom component name (if provided)
     */
    Vue.component(this.componentName, Launcher)
    Vue.use(VTooltip)
    Vue.use(VueI18n)
  }
}
export default Plugin
```

And i start to change in the file "src/Launcher.vue" "you" in the header of the chat

```
  computed: {
    chatWindowTitle() {
      if (this.title !== '') {
        return this.title
      }
      if (this.participants.length === 0) {
        return $t('participant.you_only')
      } else if (this.participants.length > 1) {
        return $t('participant.you_and_participants', { participant: 'this.participants[0].name' })
      } else {
        return 'You & ' + this.participants[0].name
      }
    }
  },
```

but i receive this error

[image: Capture d’écran 2020-06-02 à 21 46 25]

i have try few others methods as `this.$i18n` and others.
Can you help me please ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possible missing the "this" when referring to "$t" on the computed property?

```
computed: {
    chatWindowTitle() {
      if (this.title !== '') {
        return this.title
      }
      if (this.participants.length === 0) {
        return this.$t('participant.you_only')
      } else if (this.participants.length > 1) {
        return this.$t('participant.you_and_participants', { participant: 'this.participants[0].name' })
      } else {
        return 'You & ' + this.participants[0].name
      }
    }
  },
```